# The sereis $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/2^{n^2} $ converges to irrational?

Tags: convergence-divergence, irrational-numbers

> Does the sereis $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/2^{n^2} $ converges to an irrational ?

Thinking about $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/10^{n^2} $ , we can say it is an irrational number due to non-recurring decimal places.

Does this argument work for the above sereis considering binary representations? Is it that simple or is there a more analytical way? Please help.

Comment: Yes, it's just that

Comment: Yes, the property is valid independent of the base.

Comment: okay, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

If $\alpha = \frac{p}{q}$ is a rational number, then for any $k$ natural number,  $k \cdot \alpha$ cannot get closer than $\frac{1}{q}$ to an integer.

Now we have 
$$2^{n^2} \alpha = \textrm{integer} + 2^{n^2}\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{k^2}}= \textrm{integer} + \delta_n $$
where $0<\delta_n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: I didn't quite get the first line. If I select $ k=q $ then $ \alpha k= p $ is itself an integer..so it closer than $ 1/q $..isn't it? Please clarify this.

Comment: @Kishore: if not an integer, then cannot come closer than $1/q$.

Comment: Ohh..right ! I think it can be proved by using division algorithm. Am i right?  But I am still confused with the last part. Won't the integer part grow? Then what is the final conclusion ? Sorry for the inconvenience but i would be happy to understand it fully.

Comment: @Kishore: the fractional part is the key...if $\alpha = p/q$ rational ( $q>0$) then $\{k \alpha\}$ (the fractional part) is either $0$ or $\ge 1/q$. But for our $\alpha$ and convenient chosen $k$ that fractional part is $>0$ and smaller and smaller... so $\alpha \ne p/q$.